# Set tr color dynamically in blazor application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I have table which create by dynamically (stored procedure returns Datatable) and create successfully but when I click click event `getTrnDetails(batchno)` then I want to color `<tr>` for show separate other row. How can I do this?

Razor template:

```
@foreach (DataRow row in opType.Rows) 
{
   sl = 1;
   <tr>
   @foreach (DataColumn column in opType.Columns) 
   { 
      string batchno = @row[column.ColumnName].ToString();
      <td>
      @if (sl == 1) 
      {
         <i class="fas fa-eye mr-1" 
           @onclick="(()=>getTrnDetails(batchno))"  
           style="cursor: pointer;"></i> 
      } @row[column.ColumnName]
    </td>
    sl = sl + 1; 
  }
</tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with JavaScript code.

1. Provide a unique id to each `<tr>` element.
2. Pass the `<tr>` id when calling the `getTrnDetails` function.
3. Call the JavaScript function via [`JS.InvokeVoidAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-8.0#invoke-javascript-functions-without-reading-a-returned-value-invokevoidasync) function with the `rowIndex` parameter.
4. Implement your JS function in the *index.html* or separate JS file(s) (but make sure you need to attach to the *index.html*). Add the CSS class to the `<tr>` element

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS;

<table class="table">
    @foreach (DataRow row in opType.Rows)
    {
        sl = 1;
        string rowId = "row_" + rowIndex;
        <tr id="@rowId">
            @foreach (DataColumn column in opType.Columns)
            {
                string batchno = @row[column.ColumnName].ToString();

                <td>
                    @if (sl == 1)
                    {

                        <i class="fas fa-eye mr-1" @onclick="(()=>getTrnDetails(batchno, rowId))" style="cursor: pointer;">
    </i>
                    }
                    @row[column.ColumnName]
                </td>
                sl = sl + 1;
            }
        </tr>

        rowIndex++;
    }
</table>
```

```cs
int rowIndex = 1;

public async Task getTrnDetails(string batchno, string rowId)
{
    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("app.toggleTrColor", rowId);
}
```

```
<style>
    app { }

    .bg-yellow {
        background: yellow;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.app = {
         toggleTrColor: (rowId) => {
            var element = document.querySelector("tr#" + rowId);
            element.classList.toggle("bg-yellow");
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: [Demo @ Blazor Fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/tjkamp6s)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a dictionary to store the selected state of the row.

You can create a dictionary where the key is the unique identifier of the row and the value is a boolean value indicating whether the row is selected, and then initialize it to the unselected state.Here is an example you can use as a reference:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
     opType = new DataTable();

        
     opType.Columns.Add("BatchNo", typeof(string));
     opType.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
     opType.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));

        
  opType.Rows.Add("Batch1", "Data11", "Data12"); 
  opType.Rows.Add("Batch2", "Data21", "Data22");                                                         

     selectedRows = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
     foreach (DataRow row in opType.Rows)
     {
         string batchNo = row["BatchNo"].ToString(); 
         selectedRows[batchNo] = false; 
     }

     await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}
Dictionary<string, bool> selectedRows;
```

Change selected status:

```
void getTrnDetails(string batchNo)
{
       
     if (selectedRows.ContainsKey(batchNo))
     {
         selectedRows[batchNo] = !selectedRows[batchNo];
     }
}
```

Return to selected state:

```
bool IsRowSelected(string batchNo)
{
        
     return selectedRows.ContainsKey(batchNo) && selectedRows[batchNo];
}
```

foreach:

```
@foreach (DataRow row in opType.Rows)
        {
             string batchNo = row["BatchNo"].ToString();
             <tr style="background-color: @(IsRowSelected(batchNo) ? "lightgray" : "white")">
                 @foreach (DataColumn column in opType.Columns)
                 {
                     <td>
                         @if (column.ColumnName == "BatchNo")
                         {
                             <i class="fas fa-eye mr-1" @onclick="() => getTrnDetails(batchNo)" style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
                         }
                         @row[column.ColumnName]
                     </td>
                 }
             </tr>
        }
```

[image]